# Net AMQP client for IBM MQ

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, amqp

I am trying to connect to IBM MQ using AMQP 1.0 channel from my .Net Core application and I am receiving the below error:

```
    Address address = new Address("amqp://10.58.139.97:1234");
Connection connection = new Connection(address, SaslProfile.Anonymous, null, null);

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TcpTransport'.
   at Amqp.Framing.Reader.ReadBuffer
```

Comment: Which .NET AMQP library are you using?  Because IBM MQ does not include an .NET AMQP library.  Also, why not simply use the MQ .NET library?  i.e. native MQ connectivity.

Comment: I am using AMQPNetLite.Core for  .Net Core. IBM MQ does not support .Net core.

Comment: Does the server require TLS connection? The error suggests that the tcp connection is reset by the server.

Comment: AMQP package was not installed in MQ server